# Are there serious downsides to nutritional supplements?

Tags: diet, supplement

Assuming one does not overdose, or take the wrong supplements, are there significant long term downsides to taking vitamin/nutritional supplements?

I am talking here about supplements such as Vitamin D, B12, or Iron. And I'm assuming the person actually has a deficiency in them due to diet (e.g. vegetarianism, or practical limitations).